# How do i draw and position a triangle?

Tags: html, css

In my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUa9z/)  I cannot get my triangle to appear correctly.  It either goes above my text container or behind the background container.  How do I get it to stay comfortably in the middle?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="firefighter-link">
    Program Overview
</div>
<div class="firefighter-current-page">
    Program Overview
    <div class="firefighter-current-page-corner"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of what i'm trying to do.  The bottom "triangle" represents the page you are currently on.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam says, the best practice is to use a triangle.

```
.triangle{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 50px solid blue;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

Very helpful screencast on css triangles:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-drawing-and-using-css-triangles/

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using a square and rotating it, you should be using a triangle.

Try creating a div with a 0 width and 0 height and give it an 8px border. Then, make all borders transparent except for one (in your case your top border) and you'll end up with a triangle.

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot to save my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ndudD/

```
div { width:0; height:0; border: 8px solid transparent; border-top-color: #000; }
```

Comment: adam, your jsfiddle links to their home page.  btw.  awesome information im excited to see how this works.

Comment: That may have been the point. Not giving you the solution, but instead giving you the opportunity to learn it by making it yourself.

Comment: It sure did! Awesome stuff

Comment: Here's a nice list of shapes you can create using CSS with similar properties: [CSS3 Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com)